# Object.keys does not respect key type of dictionary

Tags: typescript

When I have an object typed as:

```
{ [key: number]: {...} }
```

and use Object.keys() on it, it returns a string array. I can also see that Object.keys is not defined as generic in lib.es5.d.ts, which could solve this.

I'm aware that TS is a transpiler to JS and does not change the fundamentals. What is the "TS-way" of getting the behaviour I'm looking for? And if not, is there a reason behind this? Maybe a newer version where this is resolved?

Comment: `Object.keys` is a Javascript method, and Javascript doesn't have any type annotation, nor do type annotations influence runtime behaviour…!?

Comment: [_"The `Object.keys()` static method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable **string-keyed** property names."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (Emphasis mine.) Even if you ask for the keys (indices) of an array, you get strings: `Object.keys([1, 2, 3]);` -> `[ '0', '1', '2' ]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well yes, under the hood. But when I go T[].map( (element, index ) => {}) it does indicate that the "element" is of type T. So its just strange to me that it isn't the case for Object.keys

Comment: ...that's because mapping _does_ give you the values, and the keys as numbers. It's an array method, it knows it's working with a specific kind of object. Object.keys doesn't, it gives you the keys as strings, hence the type. TypeScript is just telling you what JavaScript is going to do.

Comment: There's nothing to resolve in a newer version. There's nothing wrong. TS says it always returns an array of strings because **it always returns an array of strings**. It's not defined as generic because it isn't generic. The behaviour you seem to want would be the compiler lying to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All property names in an object are treated as strings. Even if you employ a number to establish a property, it will be converted to a string, regardless of whether you type the keys as numbers.

[See Property accessor doc for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#property_names)

> Each property name is a string or a Symbol. Any other value, including a number, is coerced to a string.

Typing the keys of an object in TypeScript provides a way to only accept specific keys when constructing the object. However, keep in mind that TypeScript does not enforce any constraints during runtime, so the standard behavior of JavaScript will prevail.

About why `Object.keys` always return an array of strings, there is a simple reason that is well explained in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870)

> Types in TS are open ended. So keysof will likely be less than all properties you would get at runtime.

During runtime, properties can be added to an object dynamically. Therefore, when `Object.keys` is invoked, we cannot be certain about the actual keys present in the object.

If you know what you are doing, and know for sure what type of keys you're expecting, you can use an assertion like this

```js
Object.keys(myObject) as keyof typeof myObject
```

Comment: Im aware of this, that it comes from JS that is, and that it is not the case during runtime because it is transpiled.  My question is why I, during TS compile time, am bugged by this? Is there a "typesafe" TS version of Object.values? I mean, I could make it myself, but I bet there's a way you're meant to do it?

Comment: You have more information in this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870

Comment: So your best choice here is assertion, calling Object.keys() and adding `as keyof ...`

Comment: Ah, beans. Could've been great if that was the standard, that is adding assertion. Could you include what you told me here in comments as your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: The assertion would be a lie, though; the runtime values **are strings**.

Comment: Thats a good answer; that an assertion or a generic parameter is not included because it doesn't reflect with how the runtime works.
Personally I'd say that's a strange argument, as it'd be a great help during development, and is why you'd use typescript in the first place over js.

Comment: Assertion would be a lie, but if you know what you are doing it can be useful

Comment: This is relevant to why you get `string[]` rather than `("prop1" | "prop2" ...)[]`, not so much rather than `number[]`.

Comment: Good point, but i guess there can always be some use case to it. Maybe to parse the keys as number, or to use it as index of an array, i don't know. Anyway the question was more about why the properties name in an object are always string, and why  `Object.keys` is not generic